# How to understand "She gives a dinner for me"?

Tags: meaning

> She gives a dinner for me.

Why not use :

> She gives a dinner to me.

Comment: My first thought is that neither is idiomatic, and that the first is ungrammatical. _But_, what's the context? What situation are you trying to describe? There's an unusual reading of the first that _is_ grammatical.

Comment: @jimsug I have no context of this sentence. I just want to analyze this sentence without any context.

Comment: @jimsug: If I want to quiz "to me", can I ask the question like that: To whom does she give a dinner?

Comment: Without context, the answer is basically: because both sentences mean something else. Without context, you question is like: "She throws a party" - why not say "She hands out food"? They are completely different sentences :)

Comment: As a side note: "To whom **does** she give" --> not "gives", the verb is "does give", does + bare infinitive.

Comment: @oerkelens Yes, you are right. I typed too fast.And I have corrected it. By the way, can I ask the question like that?

Comment: It depends what you want to ask. If she gives me a packed meal, I can ask "To whom does she give a dinner?", if she throws a party for me, I can ask "For whom is this dinner?", "For whom does she give this dinner?"

Answer (score 5):

If someone gives a dinner *for* you, it is implied that that person is hosting a dinner party *in your honour*.

If someone just gives you prepared food to eat, she gives, buys or cooks you dinner.

If she gives *a* dinner to you, she hands you a (probably) packed meal.

Comment: :What does "a dinner" mean ?

Comment: It is either an evening meal (though you might want to look up supper and dinner), or a party that centres around that meal.

Comment: That first one - is it a regional or marked construction? I'm not sure I've ever heard that. I've heard "_throw_ a dinner", though.

Comment: @jimsug: I don't know how regional it is, but it seems "give" is more common than "throw" according to [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=give+a+dinner+party%2C+throw+a+dinner+party&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgive%20a%20dinner%20party%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthrow%20a%20dinner%20party%3B%2Cc0) - I have to admit it surprises me too

Comment: You _give_ or _host_ a dinner (a formal meal, usually to honor some person or event). You _throw_ or _host_ a party (a usually _informal_ celebration of some person or event). For "a dinner", it's more than simply providing food to eat at an evening meal (note that in some places, "dinner" refers to a mid-day meal). It may include toasts, speeches, gift-giving, etc., and revolves around honoring someone or something.